# wait on a destroyed mutex not crash

Tags: c, crash

If a mutex has been destroyed, does the wait crash?  The example below does not crash in Linux:

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; 
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 

void* threadLoop() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
    printf("%d %lu Waiting\n", getpid(), pthread_self());
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 
    printf("%d %lu Return\n", getpid(), pthread_self()); 
    return NULL; 
}    

int main() { 
    printf("%d %lu main\n", getpid(), pthread_self());
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, threadLoop, NULL); 
    sleep(1); 

    printf("%d %lu destroy\n", getpid(), pthread_self());
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock); 
    sleep(1); 
    printf("%d %lu signal\n", getpid(), pthread_self());
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond); 
    pthread_join(tid, NULL); 
    printf("%d %lu done\n", getpid(), pthread_self());
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
6332 140377089791808 main
6332 140377086490304 Waiting
6332 140377089791808 destroy
6332 140377089791808 signal
6332 140377086490304 Return
6332 140377089791808 done
```

Comment: When you get into [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) land anything can happen including (but not necessarily) a crash.

Comment: You have presented an example where a wait on a mutex that has been destroyed does not crash, so evidently the answer is somewhere between "no" and "not necessarily".  The "no" option seems implausible, so we're left with "not necessarily".  I assume that you are capable of performing that analysis yourself, so what is the actual question you want answered?

Comment: On paper, don't do that (re. UB). But, from the `glibc` source, in `nptl/pthread_mutex_destroy.c`, the function will do an `atomic_load` on `.__kind`, to see if it's a "robust" mutex. If so, and it has active users, the function will return `EBUSY`. Otherwise, it uses `atomic_store` to set `.__kind` to -1 (invalid). So, nothing to cause a segfault, etc.

Comment: You don't capture and report the status of the Pthread functions you use.  You've no idea whether any of them worked, though they mostly appear to do so.  You might find that you get an error reported when using the destroyed mutex.  But using a destroyed mutex is undefined behaviour — don't do it.  Don't rely on any observed behaviour arising from undefined behaviour.  It isn't guaranteed to be reliable or portable.